# Python PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied Pathlib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to move a files from one directory to another utilizing the pathlib library, however, I am receiving a permission error in python from the following code:

```
import pathlib

#create a folder called documents with the files

my_dir = pathlib.Path.cwd()
documents = my_dir / "documents"

if not documents.exists():
    documents.mkdir()

files = [documents / "image1.png", documents / "image2.gif", documents / "image3.png", documents / "image4.jpg"]

for file in files:
    if not file.exists():
        file.touch()

#create a folder called images and move the files from docs into images

images = my_dir / "images"

if not images.exists():
    images.mkdir()

for path in documents.rglob("*.*"):
    path.replace(images / path.name)

print(images.iterdir())
```

Anyone know where I am getting it wrong? Tried running the program in Administrator mode, no luck.

The Error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\playingwfiles.py", line 25, in <module>
  path.replace(images / path.name)
File "C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39    \lib\pathlib.py", line 1395, in replace
self._accessor.replace(self, target)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Computer\\Desktop\\documents\\image1.png' -> 'C:\\Users\\Computer\\Desktop\\images\\image1.png'
```

Comment: which part of code are you having issues with?

Comment: @BijayRegmi The last few lines, I have no idea why I am receiving a PermissionError

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full text of the error message?

Comment: @dg99 Hello, I have included the error message

Comment: You get exception on the line: `path.replace(images / path.name)` According to the documentation method `replace()` does the following: `Rename this path to the target path, overwriting if that path exists.`. What does `images / path.name` in your code mean?

Comment: @Rafael `images / path.name` What I was trying to do there was replace the parent directory name `documents` with `images' and then add the `path.name` found by the `rglob()` method. I might have been overthinking that a bit...

Comment: @DexGunther I may be wrong, but I think the files, located in the directory you are trying to rename are in use. And because of that you get the exception you've reported.